# How to get older SDK and do I need to?

Tags: iphone, sdk, compatibility

I have OS 10.6 on my mac.  I started with iphone SDK for snow lepard which builds for SDK 3.0 to 3.1.2.  I'm ready to submit my app to the store.  I'd like older iphones to use it as well.  I can't find Apple's link for SDK 2.2.  Only the link for the 3.1 sdk.

Do I need to release the app built with 2.2 ?  If so where can I find it?

Can iphone users update the OS on their phones?

Thanks,

Comment: I recommend making your App 3.x only. Apple will like this and you'll have less testing. 95% of iPhone users will have this. It's only iPod Touch's bought before Summer 2009 that might have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, on my mac, (10.6.2) iphone sdk will build 'down' to 2.2.

And yes, iPhone users can upgrade (and downgrade) their OS.  -- but you knew that since you've got an iPhone for testing right?

:)

Comment: Note that you can set the base SDK lower, you just can't test it in the simulator - only the device.

Comment: But, you gotta have devices to test with :)  And, since a 3.X device can run 2.2 code - that should be good enough for the OP.

Comment: Yes I have a provisioned iphone.  Okay I found the project setting where where I can build for 2.2 on the iphone.  The simulator only goes to 3.0.  Now my problem is that I use NSPersistentStore and that is only available on 3.0.

Comment: If you're using Core Data, don't even bother looking at OS 2.x.  Targeting the fraction of users still on that older release is not worth the time and effort of reimplementing your data model in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

In the XCode, you can either specify which SDK to use to build your application or which OS version to use to test your application. See [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/120-Running_Applications/running_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH6-SW1) for more details.